# Why does a panic while panicking result in an illegal instruction?

Tags: rust, panic, illegal-instruction

Consider the following code that purposely causes a double panic:

```
use scopeguard::defer; // 1.1.0

fn main() {
    defer!{ panic!() };
    defer!{ panic!() };
}
```

I know this typically happens when a `Drop` implementation panics while unwinding from a previous panic, but why does it cause the program to issue an illegal instruction? That sounds like the code is corrupted or jumped somewhere unintended. I figure this might be system or code generation dependent but I tested on various platforms and they all issue similar errors with the same reason:

- Linux:

  ```
  thread panicked while panicking. aborting.
  Illegal instruction (core dumped)
  ```
- Windows (with `cargo run`):

  ```
  thread panicked while panicking. aborting.
  error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\tests.exe` (exit code: 0xc000001d, STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION)
  ```
- The Rust Playground:

  ```
  thread panicked while panicking. aborting.
  timeout: the monitored command dumped core
  /playground/tools/entrypoint.sh: line 11:     8 Illegal instruction     timeout --signal=KILL ${timeout} "$@"
  ```

What's going on? What causes this?

Comment: it's because you panic but catch it or something and panic twice, since the first panic didn't work, I guess rust do a ["OK I WILL DO IT MYSELF"](https://youtu.be/a8HqxpZ_rvk?t=158)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is intended.

From a [comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81895#issuecomment-775489478) by Jonas Schievink in [Why does panicking in a Drop impl cause SIGILL?](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81895):

> It calls `intrinsics::abort()`, which LLVM turns into a `ub2` instruction, which is illegal, thus SIGILL

I couldn't find any documentation for how double panics are handled, but a paragraph for [`std::intrinsics::abort()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.abort.html) lines up with this behavior:

> The current implementation of `intrinsics::abort` is to invoke an invalid instruction, on most platforms. On Unix, the process will probably terminate with a signal like `SIGABRT`, `SIGILL`, `SIGTRAP`, `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`. The precise behaviour is not guaranteed and not stable.

Curiously, this behavior is different from calling [`std::process::abort()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.abort.html), which always terminates with `SIGABRT`.

The illegal instruction of choice on x86 is `UD2` (I think a typo in the comment above) a.k.a. an [undefined instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud) which is paradoxically reserved and documented to not be an instruction. So there is no corruption or invalid jump, just a quick and loud way to tell the OS that something has gone very wrong.

Comment: My assumption would be that `core::intrinsics::abort` (which `std::intrinsics::abort` is a re-export of) is used during double-panics because it must work even with `#![no_std]`, and that `core::instrinsics::abort` uses the illegal instruction because the `core` library cannot use functionality from the operating system.